# iOS app keeps showing red popup in notification tray until you go to main web site

Tags: bug, notifications, ios-app

I'm using the SE iOS app version 1.3.0.

This morning I woke up and checked the app.  It showed a red popup with "3" in the notification tray.  One was a comment so I went to it.  That should have cleared the "3" from the tray, but I noticed that whenever I closed the app and went back into it, the notification tray kept showing "3".  Even after I force closed the app and relaunched it, it still showed "3" in the notification tray.

Finally I went to SE on a desktop PC and clicked on the notification tray there.  Then I went back to the iOS app and the notification tray finally didn't show "3" anymore.